# Tennis is good to lose weight?

Tags: weight-loss

I've heard that tennis is not a good sport to lose weight, that someone who plays tennis just loses sugar in the blood. Is it maybe because the style of this sport, that we don't need endurance to play it? For instance, in running we need to have a kind of a constant speed, in tennis we don't have a balanced physical exertion because most of the time we sprint.

Is that true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why downvoted??

Comment: Have you ever seen a good tennis player being heavy or fat?

Comment: @Freakyuser this has nothing to do with my question!

Comment: Don't worry, I haven't downvoted or close voted your question. Let us wait for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Combined with a healthy diet, any physical activity can help with weight loss.** However the key is to ensure your diet is in order first. Eating whole foods, minimising sugar and refined carbohydrates and a calroie deficit are all necessary for good health. There are plenty of questions on this site that cover dietary changes for weight loss that are worth reading.

There are lots of reasons to workout, however exercise without a change in diet rarely leads directly to weight loss.

However, tennis has a lot of other good aspects. It requires flexibility, hand eye coordination and the ability to change direction. It emphasises quick explosive bursts of energy, not unlike High Intensity Interval Trainning. But your assertion that it doesn't require endurance is not true. Professional level tennis matches can last for hours, and even at the amateur level, even though you have periods where you are standing still your body will still be in a heightened state both attempting to recover from the last burst and getting ready for the next one.

Comment: I know that, but tennis is better or worse to loss weight than running for example?

Comment: If you like tennis more than running, tennis is better.